# Error with npm install semantic-ui-react semantic-ui-css using React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, semantic-ui

[Error shown with the semantic UI installation using npm install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmWnJ.png)

how to solve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error might have arisen due to version conflicts.

Try this:

```
npm i semantic-ui-react semantic-ui-css --legacy-peer-deps
```